# Find the range of surface integral using spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

> Let $S$ be a section of sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$ with $x\ge1$ and $y\ge1$(like wedge shape). Compute the area of $S$ finding the range of surface integral over $S$ via spherical coordinates.

If the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$ parametrized $X(\theta,\phi)=(\sqrt{3}\cos\theta\sin\phi,\sqrt{3}\sin\theta\sin\phi,\sqrt{3}\cos\phi)$ with $0\le\theta\le2\pi,~0\le\phi\le\pi$, then how to find the range of $\theta$ for $S$?

I tried $x=\sqrt{3}\cos\theta\sin\phi\ge1$ and $y=\sqrt{3}\sin\theta\sin\phi\ge1$, but i couldn't find the common range for $\theta$.

Also, is it true that the range of $\phi$ is $\cos^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})\le\phi\le\cos^{-1}(-1/\sqrt{3})$?

I'm not sure about that. Give some advice. Thank you!

Comment: Try to make a 3D sketch of surface, $ 0< \theta <  \pi/4 $ is sufficient by virtue of symmetry.

Comment: It is not sufficient. The value of $\theta$ depends on $\phi$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Actually Cartesian  coordinates are more suitable for the computation, but problem is given that way;

To workaround, since

$$ r=R \cos \phi , R= \sqrt{3},$$

$$ x_1= R \cos  \phi \cos\theta ;\, y_1= R \cos \phi \sin \theta $$
are constants and the intersection point is 
$$ (x,y,z)= (1,1,\pm 1), $$

it helps in finding integration limits.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem as i wished:

$$\iint_{S_{0}}dS=\int_{\cos^{-1}\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}^{\pi-\cos^{-1}\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}\int_{\sin^{-1}\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}\sin\phi}\right)}^{\cos^{-1}\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}\sin\phi}\right)}3\sin\phi\,d\theta\,d\phi=(2-\sqrt{3})\pi.$$

Comment: Would  serve generalization purpose if you take limits in symbols and evaluate particular cases.